# Hola quisiera saber como puedo sumar valores de filas duplicadas

Tags: sql

es decir si tengo un id  que se duplica y tienen saldos diferentes quedarme con id único pero con la suma de los que se duplican .
Por ejemplo tengo .

Id   usuario saldo
Id1   pedro   $100
Id2   Rosa     $300
Id3   ruben   $100
Id4    susi   $200
Id4    Carlos $300

La salida que busco sería
Id    saldo
Id1      $100
Id2      $300
Id3      $100
Id4      $500

Comment: Has probado algo? Revisa [ask] para realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Pues escribir la consulta que has intentado y la estructura de las tablas, pero es fácil de resolver con un GROUP BY y con un SUM.

Comment: Dale un formato correcto a tu pregunta para que pueda entenderse mejor